# Is the $\{x \in \Bbb R : x \ne 0\}$ set open, close or neither?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is the $\{x \in \Bbb R : x \ne 0\}$ set open, close or neither?

The answer is open. However, I can't see why.

Set $A :=\{x \in \Bbb R : x \ne 0\}$. Following the definition it will be open if for every $a$ from $A$ and any positive $ϵ$ the $V_ϵ(a)$ ⊆ $A$. Now, my intuition says, that if we take $a$ such that it will be really close to $0$ and $ϵ$ be big enough, then $ϵ$ neighbourhood would not be contained in $A$ since it will contain $0$ too.

Can you, please, explain it to me?

Comment: It's not about taking $\epsilon$ large enough, it's about whether there's room to fit in _some_ $\epsilon$.  Take $x$ as close as you like to $0$ and choose $\epsilon < x/2$; your neighbourhood then doesn't include $0$.

Comment: $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: x\neq 0\}^c = \{0\}$, which is closed

Comment: It's a union of two open intervals

Comment: $\epsilon$ is kind of "flexible" range: for any small $a$ given, you take a smaller $\epsilon$ - if that $\epsilon$ exists you say that the set is open. Note again: you're taking a particular $\epsilon$.

Comment: @TheSimpli This is not set theory, please do not add the tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to be very careful with the quantifiers here.

A set $A$ will be open if for every $a \in A$ *there is some* $\epsilon$ which has $V_{\epsilon} \subseteq A$, not *all $\epsilon$*.

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your definition of open set. It doesn't have to hold for **any** positive $\epsilon$ but for **some** positive $\epsilon$. Now do you see why $A$ is open?

Answer (score 1):

To show that a set $A$ is open, pick an element, and you just show that there is an open ball such that the open ball resides in $A$.

We do not have to worry about open balls with large radius, we just have to find one that is sufficiently small that resides in the set.

In particular, if $a$ is pick, you can choose your radius to be $|a|$ and it will reside in the set.

Answer (score 0):

We know that this set is open since $$\forall x\in A\quad,\quad\exists \epsilon\quad,\quad (x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\in A$$for example take $\epsilon=\dfrac{|x|}{10}$ , but it is not closed. Take the convergent sequence $$a_n=\dfrac{1}{n}$$whose limit doesn't belong to $A$ while the terms do.